# Problema de acentuação ao recuperar registros no SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server

Quando vou recuperar registros de um banco SQL Serve com PHP aparecem erros na acentuação.

Porém no banco, os acentos estão corretos. Tem alguma forma de tratar isso com o PHP? Não tenho permissões para alterar o *collation* do banco.

*Collation* do banco: Latin1_General_CI_AS

Arquivo de conexão com o banco:

```
$host='xxxxxx';
$user='xxxxx';
$database='xxxxx';
$pass='xxxxx';

$con=mssql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Erro de conexão com o banco de dados"); 
mssql_select_db("$database") or die ("Erro ao selecionar banco de dados");
```

Campos no banco:

[image: Campos no banco]

Resultado da consulta com PHP

[image: Resultado da consulta]

Comment: Já tentou usar `escape` ?

Comment: Não.. como se usa? não conheço

Comment: Mas se os acentos estão corretos no banco então não é necessário alterar a collation

Comment: Edita sua pergunta com as partes que estão com problema @AmandaOliveiradeLima

Comment: Qual a Collation e o tipo do campo (nvarchar) ?

Comment: @gmsantos, não tenho acesso à estrutura do banco para ver o tipo do campo. Mas a Collation é Latin1_General_CI_AS

Comment: Amanda, clique em [edit] e insira os comentários importantes no corpo da pergunta (collation). Forneça também como você está conectando o PHP com o SQL Server (é por PDO?)

Comment: @gmsantos, editei lá

Comment: Colocar header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO8859-1'); resolve?

Comment: Aeeeee @gmsantos esse funcionou, muuuito obrigada!!

Comment: @AmandaOliveiradeLima converti o comentário para uma resposta. Caso tenha resolvido seu problema, você pode marcá-la como correta. Para entender como as coisas funcionam por aqui comece fazendo um [tour]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Encontrei a solução para este problema de uma forma muito simples. Ao imprimir a string, usei antes a função

`utf8_encode($variavel_contendo_string)`

e o problema foi resolvido!

Essa função codifica a string para utf-8.

Answer (score 3):

Procure utilizar um Collation igual em toda sua aplicação.

Já que você não pode alterar o Banco, configure o PHP para trabalhar com Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1):

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');
```

Ou no arquivo `php.ini`

```
default_charset = "iso-8859-1"
```

Além da configuração do PHP e Banco de dados, é preciso alterar o charset das suas páginas para trabalhar com ISO-8859-1 ao invés de UTF-8.

Comment: Resolveu o problema da acentuação dos campos do banco, porém bagunçou a acentuação do restante da página. Alterei no header de UTF-8 para  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO8859-1"> e não funciona

Comment: Amanda, tente verificar o charset do arquivo `.html` ou `.php`. Éstá em uft-8?

Comment: Não, eu alterei todos os charset para iso-8859-1

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função do PHP:`html_entity_decode($valor);`

Comment: Na minha opinião está é a melhor resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar [`sqlsrv_connect`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sqlsrv-connect.php) na qual existe o parametro `CharacterSet UTF-8`.

```
$host="xxxxxx";
$user="xxxxx";
$database="xxxxx";
$pass="xxxxx";

$connArr = array(
    "Database"     => $databae,
    "UID"          => $user,
    "PWD"          => $pass,
    "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8"
);

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($host, $connArr) or die("Erro de conexão com o banco de dados");
```

Comment: Essa função não funcionou. Deu o seguinte erro:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in /var/www/html/financeiro/core/includes/conect.php on line 17

Answer (score 0):

1ª Alternativa:

Abra o arquivo `.php` no notepad++ e vá no botão menu `formatar` e selecione a opção: `Codificação em UTF-8 (sem BOM)`, é possivel que o arquivo fonte do PHP não esteja `utf-8`.

2ª Alternativa:

A página `.html` que está renderizando não esta no padrão utf-8, então adicione esta linha a ela:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

3ª Alternativa:

Adicione isto no inicio do seu arquivo `.php`

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

4ª Alternativa:

Adicione a seguinte linha ao arquivo `.htaccess`

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

5ª Alternativa:

Edite a seguinte linha no arquivo `php.ini` para ficar como abaixo:

```
default_charset = "UTF-8"
```

6ª Alternativa:

Caso não tenha acesso ao arquivo `php.ini` adicione a seguitne linha no topo do documento `.php`:

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
```

7ª Alternativa:

```
ini_set('mssql.charset', 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: Nem sempre UFT-8 irá funcionar, depende da collation do banco.

Comment: Nenhuma dessas alternativas funcionou :/

Comment: Os acentos estão realmente perfeitos no banco? qual a collation do banco?

Comment: Sim @ricardo, os acentos estão perfeitos no banco, só dá problema quando tento exibir no php. A Collation é Latin1_General_CI_AS

Comment: @AmandaOliveiradeLima Adicionei novas alternativas.

Comment: @ricardo, nenhum funcionou ainda rs

Comment: Geralmente esse erro ocorre por causa do formato do arquivo no caso página que foi salvo errado. Infelizmente para o seu caso não funcionou. Mas na maioria das vezes com as modificações acima isso funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Existem respostas que já fazem uma boa instrução de como modelar sua aplicação para a **mesma codificação** do banco de dados.

Entretanto, quero deixar minha resposta para ser utilizada por quem quer manter sua aplicação em `UTF-8`e utilizar um banco de dados em **codificação diferente**.

Converta os dados em tempo de `fetch` utilizando sobrecarga, como neste exemplo:

```
class DrivePDOUtf8 extends DrivePDO
{
    protected function toUtf8($dados)
    {
        if (is_array($dados) || is_object($dados)) {
            foreach ($dados as $i => $r) {
                if (is_array($r) || is_object($r)) {
                    $dados[$i] = $this->toUtf8($r);
                } else {
                    $dados[$i] = utf8_encode($r);
                }
            }
        } else {
            $dados = utf8_encode($dados);
        }

        return $dados;
    }

    public function fetch($sql, $mode = null, $all = false)
    {
        $fetch = parent::fetch($sql, $mode, $all);

        return  $this->toUtf8($fetch);
    }
}
```