# Interrogação no lugar da acentuação C# e SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

Boa tarde pessoal, eu tenho uma aplicação em C# com banco de dados SQL Server,
o problema é que as palavras que tem letras acentuadas, no lugar dessas letras aparecem losangos com um ponto de interrogação no meio como na imagem abaixo, quando eu insiro e altero palavras não da esse erro, isso só está acontecendo
com palavras com letras acentuadas que já são existentes no banco. Podem me ajudar?

Agradeço desde já. Abraço

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bom, estou utilizando programação em camadas, a camada Modelos, que é onde fica a classe, a camada DAL, que é onde fica a conexão com o banco, a camada BLL, que é onde fica a regra de negócio e por fim a camada UIWindows, que é onde fica o código do funcionamento do form como códigos dos botões, exibição no grid e etc.
Abaixo vou postar somente o trecho de consulta das camadas DAL, BLL e UIWindows, a Modelos é irrelevante porque só armazena os atributos da classe.

Modelos:

```
namespace Biblioteca.Modelos
{
public class CddModelos
{
    private string _codigoCdd;

    public string CodigoCdd
    {
        get { return _codigoCdd; }
        set { _codigoCdd = value; }
    }



    private string _descricaoCdd;

    public string DescricaoCdd
    {
        get { return _descricaoCdd; }
        set { _descricaoCdd = value; }
    }

}
}
```

DAL:

```
public DataTable Listagem_cdd()
    {
        DataTable tabela = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Cdd", Dados.StringDeConexao);
        da.Fill(tabela);
        return tabela;
    }
```

BLL:

```
public DataTable Listagem_cdd()
    {
        CddDAL obj = new CddDAL();

        return obj.Listagem_cdd();
    }
```

UIWindows:

```
//Método parra carregar o grid
    public void AtualizaGridCdd()
    {
        // Comunicação com a Camada BLL
        CddBLL obj = new CddBLL();
        dataGridViewCdd.DataSource = obj.Listagem_cdd();

        dataGridViewCdd.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Código";
        dataGridViewCdd.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Descrição";

        // Atualizando os objetos TextBox
        textBoxCodigo_cdd.Text = dataGridViewCdd[0, dataGridViewCdd.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();
        textBoxDescricao_cdd.Text = dataGridViewCdd[1, dataGridViewCdd.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();

      }


private void dataGridViewCdd_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridViewCdd.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Código";
        dataGridViewCdd.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Descrição";

        // Atualizando os objetos TextBox
        textBoxCodigo_cdd.Text = dataGridViewCdd[0, dataGridViewCdd.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();
        textBoxDescricao_cdd.Text = dataGridViewCdd[1, dataGridViewCdd.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();

    }
```

Comment: Sua aplicação usa qual codificação? O banco está em qual codificação?

Comment: O banco está usando codificação Latin1_General_CI_AS e eu não tenho permissões do sql server para mudar. Na aplicação não está especificado.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/74567/problema-de-acentua%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ao-recuperar-registros-no-sql-server?rq=1

Comment: Poste a rotina que preenche o datagrid para melhor te ajudarmos. Qual tecnologia de acesso a dados você está utilizando?

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta @ismael , muito obrigado!

Comment: Aah, a tecnologia de acesso a dados que estou usando é o sgbd SQL Server