# Como corrigir acentuação consulta dados sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Bom dia!

Galera, como faço para realizar a correção das acentuações dos dados vindo de um select no sql server. Pois alguns registros que eram pra vir como Sérgio, está vindo SÃ©rgio.

Comment: Isso é porque eles foram inseridos assim. Você deve corrigir a inserção, e não o output.

Comment: Mas como posso fazer isso na consulta? Tem alguma função?

Comment: Da uma melhorada na sua pergunta, explicar como os dados estão sendo inseridos e como estão sendo recuperados, ou seja, é uma aplicação que faz isso ou é direto no banco ?

Comment: @RenanBessa não sei se existe função no SQL. O que você percebe é um problema de encoding, então existe a possibilidade de que uma aplicação não tenha esse problema i.e.: na aplicação a acentuação aparecerá correta se a aplicação utilizar o mesmo encoding de quem gerou o insert.

Comment: @RenanBessa: qual é a linguagem do aplicativo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Renan, se precisas obter esses dados corretamente em tempo de execução, creio que a solução esteja abaixo.

> A função foi retirada [deste link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31064459/1545939)

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.UTF8_TO_NVARCHAR(@in varchar(MAX))
   RETURNS NVarChar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @out NVarChar(MAX), @i int, @c int, @c2 int, @c3 int, @nc int

   SELECT @i = 1, @out = ''

   WHILE (@i <= Len(@in))
   BEGIN
      SET @c = Ascii(SubString(@in, @i, 1))

      IF (@c < 128)
      BEGIN
         SET @nc = @c
         SET @i = @i + 1
      END
      ELSE IF (@c > 191 AND @c < 224)
      BEGIN
         SET @c2 = Ascii(SubString(@in, @i + 1, 1))

         SET @nc = (((@c & 31) * 64 /* << 6 */) | (@c2 & 63))
         SET @i = @i + 2
      END
      ELSE
      BEGIN
         SET @c2 = Ascii(SubString(@in, @i + 1, 1))
         SET @c3 = Ascii(SubString(@in, @i + 2, 1))

         SET @nc = (((@c & 15) * 4096 /* << 12 */) | ((@c2 & 63) * 64 /* << 6 */) | (@c3 & 63))
         SET @i = @i + 3
      END

      SET @out = @out + NChar(@nc)
   END
   RETURN @out
END
```

As consultas abaixo checam se deu certo ou não.

```
-- Essa te retorna todos os registros da tabela

SELECT * ,
       foo = dbo.UTF8_TO_NVARCHAR ( sua_coluna_com_problemas )
  FROM sua_tabela

-- Essa te retorna apenas os registros que possuem algum problema de ENCODE

SELECT * ,
       foo = dbo.UTF8_TO_NVARCHAR ( sua_coluna_com_problemas )
  FROM sua_tabela
WHERE sua_coluna_com_problemas <> dbo.UTF8_TO_NVARCHAR(sua_coluna_com_problemas)
```

Comment: isso mesmo amigo, deu certo

Comment: salvou minha vida, vlw

Answer (score 0):

Isto se deve a diferença entre a codificação de caractere utilizada na coluna e a codificação utilizada no aplicativo. Deve-se verificar qual é o COLLATE da coluna e então configurar no aplicativo a mesma codificação (*pagecode*). Também é possível o uso de COLLATE na consulta que recupera as linhas, de modo a compatibilizar com o *pagecode* utilizado na aplicação.

No SQL Server é possível definir COLLATE em 3 níveis: (1) na instância; (2) no banco de dados e (3) na coluna.

Sugestão de leitura:

- [Suporte a agrupamentos e a Unicode](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support)
- [COLLATE](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/statements/collations)

Tópicos semelhantes:

- [Problema de acentuação ao recuperar registros no SQL Server](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/74567/problema-de-acentua%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ao-recuperar-registros-no-sql-server)